# What is the best way to check a field is blank 3 days after being created?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

We create meetings as Events and have three Activity Custom Text Fields: Meeting Notes, Next Meeting and Next Steps.

We'd like to set up an email notification to email a group of users if these 3 fields are left blank 3 days after an event is created.

I've looked into workflows and process builder and can't work out the best way to do this.

Comment: I think Time Based Workflow if the best option here.

Comment: Note that  time-based workflow is automatically cancelled if it doesn't meet the prerequisites anymore any time before the execution date. So this would exactly meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using Process Builder. For this, create a checkbox (Send Email) on Event.

**First evaluation criteria** of the Process can be anything (or nothing),so all events enter this process by default.

And in the schedule section, add the condition as "3 Days After Event Created Date".  And the schedule action will be "Record Update", here add the criteria to check if the 3 fields are blank/empty/null and then Update the "Send Email" checkbox.

> In **STOP** block, make sure to choose "continue evaluating next steps"!

[image]

**2nd Evaluation Criteria :** Below the 1st Evaluation criteria (I mean, the False of the 1st decision box), add a new criteria condition and check if "Send Email" button "is changed" to TRUE, and then set the immediate action as "Email Alert".

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you forgot a few steps to make that happen: "For processes that are set to run when a record is created or edited, scheduled actions remain in the queue only as long as the criteria for those actions are still valid. If a record no longer matches the criteria, Salesforce removes the scheduled actions for that record from the queue." and you have to check "Yes" Under advanced